# Maven Compile Not Creating .class

Tags: java, maven

I'm building my Maven project from the command line (i.e. not via the IDE) with the following command:

```
mvn package
```

However, the resources is copied into `target/classes` but the folder is otherwise empty (i.e. the class files aren't being built).

The output of my package command is as follows:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building graph-utils-server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ graph-utils-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ graph-utils-server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /home/bakerj/graphutilsserver/src/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ graph-utils-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/bakerj/graphutilsserver/src/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ graph-utils-server ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ graph-utils-server ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ graph-utils-server ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/bakerj/graphutilsserver/src/target/graph-utils-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.013 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-14T15:14:12+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/943M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note, the root of my project is `/home/bakerj/graphutilserver/src` (i.e. that's where the POM is and where I'm running Maven from). There is a `src` folder beneath that holding the actual code.

I can see that is picking up the 12 source files I have, but they are not being compiled (or at least not placed into the `target/classes` folder as expected.

```
$ mvn -v

Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.10.0-42-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Any suggestions on what's going wrong?

**Update** - POM file included below (I've commented out `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in case that was causing the issue, but the result is the same if it is uncommented).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>graph-utils-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>graph-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-to-graph-mapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AWS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.276</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gremlin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>tinkergraph-gremlin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-console</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JanusGraph -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-lucene</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> -->
</project>
```

**Update** - As it's causing some confusion, here is my folder structure:

```
$ pwd
/home/bakerj/graphutilsserver/src

$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── myproject
        │       └── graphutils
        │           └── server
        │               ├── controllers
        │               │   ├── ClearGraph.java
        │               │   ├── CreateGraph.java
        │               │   ├── LoadGraph.java
        │               │   ├── MergeGraph.java
        │               │   └── TransformGraph.java
        │               ├── exceptions
        │               │   ├── BadRequestException.java
        │               │   ├── NotFoundException.java
        │               │   └── ServerErrorException.java
        │               ├── GraphUtilsServer.java
        │               └── utils
        │                   ├── ConfigUtils.java
        │                   ├── FileUtils.java
        │                   └── S3Utils.java
        └── resources
            └── janusgraph-hbase.properties

13 directories, 14 files
```

**Update** - I've just built the same code (checked out via Git, so should be identical) on a different machine and it works fine. So it would appear to be something to do with my configuration rather than the code itself. Both computers are running the same version of Java and Maven. Any thoughts on where to look for differences?

Comment: We can see from the log that sources were compiled: `Compiling 12 source files to /home/bakerj/graphutilsserver/src/target/classes`. Are you sure that output folder is empty? And your folder is a little confusing with that `src/target` part...

Comment: Fairly sure, an `ls -a` in `target/classes` gives: `.  ..  janusgraph-hbase.properties`

Comment: `pwd` returns `/home/bakerj/graphutilsserver/src/target/classes` and its empty?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct directory. It's empty apart from the `janusgraph-hbase.properties` file which is a file from `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Could you show your pom.xml?

Comment: pom.xml added above

Comment: Why is it compiling into the source directory? It's not source. Are you ending up with the package, e.g., a war or jar?

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'm not sure what you mean? It is a little confusing because I have two `src` directories (for reasons beyond my control, but changing the name of the top level one doesn't make a difference). The Java/Maven project is all contained within the top `src` directory, and there's another `src` directory below that which is the 'traditional' `src` directory.

Comment: @JamesBaker I reproduced your issue. Then I removed the dependencies marked as `Gremlin` and `JanusGraph`, and after that maven compiles sources as expected. Still don't know the reason, but better than nothing I think.

Comment: @JamesBaker Any time you deviate from the standard Maven project layout it's almost always a headache. My point was to determine whether or not you were getting the package--the final product, which is what packaging does.

Comment: @DaveNewton the final package was made, but with no compiled classes in it.

Comment: It looks like the `maven-compiler-plugin` (or possibly `javac` under the hood) is crashing. I turned on `verbose` logging in the `maven-compiler-plugin` and the output seems to end earlier than projects that do build correctly (it finishes with `last round: false` whereas successful projects get to `last round: true`).